# Git Submodule Automatic Push

Tags: git, cocoapods

Let me explain my (potentially incorrect) thought process before I get into the details.

We have a very large repo that contains many uncompiled libraries that developers are working on regularly. We have a script to build all of these libraries that are outputted into a folder name `Published` I'd like to have this `Published` directory as a submodule so I've set that up I'd like to have the process be:

```
sh BuildLibraries.sh`
git add . //add modified (the new libraries) 
git commit -m "Rebuilt Libraries"
git push
```

but this doesn't work with submodules, because they are their own repository. Perhaps submodules is not what I want, what else can I do? can I make this work cleanly with submodules?

The reason I want these in a separate repo in the first place is we are using [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) in an iOS project to use these libraries as dependancies but using the main repo takes WAY to log for cocoapods to "pre-download" the repo. We've tried using an orphan branch, but it still downloads the whole repo first. I'll tag cocoapods in case, some one else had this issue.

Thank you for all and any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is cd into the repo, that's all a submodule is.

Comment: yea, I got that. Just seeing if there was a way to have the main project track it. I ended up just using the git commands within the script and delete the binary before I add so there's no merge conflicts. It's not ideal, but it works for what we need now until we upload the binaray to http server.